# Web API Basic authentication always unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API with only one user, I'm trying to use the basic authentication to protect it but it always returns code 401 unauthorized.

This is my code:

**Class BasicAuthenticationAttribute**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute: AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{   
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    else
    {
        // Gets header parameters  
        string authenticationString = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
        string originalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationString));

        // Gets username and password  
        string usrename = originalString.Split(':')[0];
        string password = originalString.Split(':')[1];

        // Validate username and password  
        if (!CheckUser.Login(usrename, password))
        {
            // returns unauthorized error  
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }

    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
}
}
```

**Class Checkuser**

```
using System;

public class CheckUser
{
public static bool Login(string username, string password)
{
    if (username == "user" && password == "mypassword")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

The API Controller

```
public class adduserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, BasicAuthentication]
    [Route("api/user/{email}")]
    public string adduser(string email)
    {
        string country_code = "";

        string username = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

        return "Welcome";
}
```

**This is my JQuery function:**

```
var token = '';
var headers = {};
if (token) {
headers.Authorization = 'Basic YWhdZWQer5WhtZWRAMjAxNw==';
}

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://mywebapi.com',
headers: headers
}).done(function (data) {
self.result(data);
})
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code!! Please help

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure about `YWhdZWQer5WhtZWRAMjAxNw==`?

Comment: This is my base 64 user and password

Comment: Have you debugged it, and seen that _user_ is indeed `"user"` and _password_ is indeed `"mypassword"` at the time of your check?

Comment: Your login method can simply be `return (username == "user" && password == "mypassword")` by the way :)

Comment: It keeps asking me about the credentials but never go to the checking user function, I don't know why??

Comment: `This is my base 64 user and password` @DainaHodges I don't think it is correct. It should the in the form `username:password` but the one in question is `ah]ed������`

Comment: How did you get your `base64`? I tried with "user" and "mypassword" and I had this: `dXNlcjpteXBhc3N3b3Jk` . You can try with that

Comment: @AlfMoh I only wrote fake passwords here, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty token, then you set your headers *if that token is not empty*, so you never set any headers...

```
var token = '';
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Basic YWhdZWQer5WhtZWRAMjAxNw==';
}
```

Try

```
if (!token) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For a assignment, I was trying to send a post request with a given token(no user and password values, I just had API token), this did not work for me :

```
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
     "converted base 64 token / api token ");
```

This help me to be authenticate, and solved my problem :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic JEcYcEMyantZV095WVc3G2JtVjNZbWx1");
```